# How to limit where my <style type="text/css"> tag is applied to

Tags: html, css

I am using the following style rules:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #939393;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul li ul.dropdown{
    min-width: 125px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
}
ul li ul.dropdown li{
    display: block;
}</style>
```

This is the only area where I want my style to be applied to:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The style tag is being applied to ALL sections on my page with a `<ul>` or `<li>` but I only want it to be applied to the code above. How can I limit it?

Comment: Why the -1 vote? The question is a basic question about CSS but OP was clear and provided code sample.

Answer (score 3):

Uniquely identify the target element(s):

```
<ul id="targetElement">
    ...
</ul>
```

Then use that identifier in the CSS rules:

```
ul#targetElement{
    ...
}
ul#targetElement li{
    ...
}
...
```

Any CSS will be applied to the entire document.  You'd adjust your CSS selectors to target more specific parts of the document.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The solution worked, however it seems to shift my dropdown menu to the right and leaves a little block on the left as shown in the link.

http://pasteboard.co/2CHamXiu.png

Any idea why it is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes on the stuff you want this to apply to so that it doesn't impact the display of the regular ul and li elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML id's or classes to apply styles. I would usually recommend classes over id's in css.

See the example below:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.styled-list{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul.styled-list li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul.styled-list li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul.styled-list li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #939393;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul.styled-list li ul.dropdown{
    min-width: 125px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}
ul.styled-list li:hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
}
ul.styled-list li ul.dropdown li{
    display: block;
}</style>


<ul class="styled-list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

For CSS rules that would only ever apply to a single element on a page, it makes sense to use html id attributes. However, since this markup seems to be for a dropdown menu, which could be used multiple times on a page, using a class name as a CSS selector would promote better code reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The solution worked, however it seems to shift my dropdown menu to the right and leaves a little block on the left as shown in the link.

http://pasteboard.co/2CHamXiu.png

Any idea why it is doing this?

Comment: You could try adding `padding: 0; list-style: none` under `ul.styled-list li ul.dropdown`. Originally, you were applying these styles to all `ul` elements on the page, including `ul.dropdown`. When you added `.styled-list`, the `ul.dropdown` element reverted to the default for `ul` elements, which is to have some padding on the left.